# Trouble selecting quantity out of drop down in watir

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, watir

I have never run into an issue with being able to select a value in a drop down, so I'm not sure how this is different. First, here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="hn-select-content hn-select-expand" ng-class="{'open-to-left':openToLeft, 'expand-to-left':expandToLeft}" ng-transclude="" style="">
    <ul class="qty-discount whiteBackground border border-hn-secondary-lt text-small ng-scope" scroll-lock="">
        <li float-container="">
            <div class="float-cont">
            <ul class="text-small">
                <li class="selected ng-isolate-scope HN-Item-Opt-Sel" li="" <="" on-option-select="changeQuantity(val)" value="1" option="1" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel selected':atcData.quantity == 1}" hn-select-option="">
                    <div class="hn-select-option ng-binding">1</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li float-container="">
            <div class="text-hn-red float-cont">
                <div scroller="qty-discount" floater="" style="">
                    <span> 10% Off </span>
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="text-small">
                <li class="ng-isolate-scope" li="" <="" on-option-select="changeQuantity(val)" value="2" option="2" ng-class="{'HN-Item-Opt-Sel selected':atcData.quantity == 2}" hn-select-option="">
                    <div class="hn-select-option ng-binding">2</div>
                </li>
```

I want to select a specific option. in this case, I have a variable set for the quantity, and it's set to 2.

This it the code from the step that is failing:

```
@browser.div(:id, 'hn_modal_contentIV').div(:text, '1').when_present.click
    @browser.ul(:class, 'whiteBackground border border-hn-secondary-lt text-small ng-scope').div(:text, quantity).when_present(5).click
    @browser.span(:class, 'redText floatRight marginTopOnly3px').wait_until_present(10)
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 5 seconds, waiting for {:text=>"2", :tag_name=>"div"} to become present
```

The drop down box opens, I just can't get the value to be selected.

I have tried a few other variations, but none have worked. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Hopefully there is something small that I'm just missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the HTML, shouldn't the locator be `@browser.ul(:class, 'qty-discount whiteBackground border border-hn-secondary-lt text-small ng-scope').div(:text, quantity).when_present(5).click`?

Comment: @orde, still getting the error: Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 5 seconds, waiting for {:text=>"2", :tag_name=>"div"} to become present

Comment: I'd suggest removing the timeout, which will expose any `unable to locate element` exceptions and let you know if your element and/or locator is accurate.

Comment: @orde, I changed the line to `@browser.ul(:class, 'qty-discount whiteBackground border border-hn-secondary-lt text-small ng-scope').div(:text, quantity).when_present.click` and got the same error `Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 90 seconds, waiting for {:text=>"2", :tag_name=>"div"} to become present`

Comment: Looks like something javascripty. try .li(value: '2').div

Comment: @Titus, that confused me. What should the line of code look like?

Comment: If watir is timing out in 90 seconds, I'd have to assume the element either doesn't exist or is somehow not visible (even after that extended interval).  Maybe your class locators are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, before this code, HTML must have an select list, perhaps this select list have the attribute `"display: none"`, then you can:

1. `browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('[id of this select list ]').style.display = 'block';")`
2. `browser.select(:id => '[id of this select]').option(:text => '[text that you need]').select`